Calculate Windowed Event Chains
Given a Polars DataFrame
data = pl.DataFrame({"user_id": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], "event": [False, True, True, False, True, True, True, False, False]

I wish to calculate a column event_chain which counts the streak of times where a user has an event, where in any of the previous 4 rows they also had an event. Every time a new event happens, when the user already has a streak active, the streak counter is incremented, it should be then set to zero if they don't have another event for another 4 rows



user_id
event
event_chain
reason for value




1
False
0
no events yet


1
True
0
No events in last 4 rows (not inclusive of current row)


1
True
1
event this row, and 1 event in last 4 rows


1
False
1
Does not reset to 0 as there is an event within the next 4 rows


1
True
2
event this row and event last 4 rows, increment the streak


2
True
0
No previous events


2
True
1
Event this row and in last 4 rows for user


2
False
0
No event this row, and no events in next 4 rows for user, resets to 0


2
False
0




I have working code as follows to do this, but I think there should be a cleaner way to do it
        data.with_columns(
         rows_since_last_event=pl.int_range(pl.len()).over("user_id")
          - pl.when("event").then(pl.int_range(pl.len())).forward_fill()
          .over("user_id"),
          rows_till_next_event=pl.when("event").then(pl.int_range(pl.len()))
          .backward_fill().over("user_id") - pl.int_range(pl.len()).over("athlete_id")
         )
        .with_columns(
            chain_event=pl.when(
                pl.col("event")
                .fill_null(0)
                .rolling_sum(window_size=4, min_periods=1)
                .over("user_id")
                - pl.col("event").fill_null(0)
                > 0
            )
            .then(1)
            .otherwise(0)
        )
        .with_columns(
            chain_event_change=pl.when(
                pl.col("chain_event").eq(1),
                pl.col("chain_event").shift().eq(0),
                pl.col("rows_since_last_event").fill_null(5) > 3,
            )
            .then(1)
            .when(
                pl.col("congested_event").eq(0),
                pl.col("congested_event").shift().eq(1),
                pl.col("rows_till_next_event").fill_null(5) > 3,
            )
            .then(1)
            .otherwise(0)
        )
        .with_columns(
            chain_event_identifier=pl.col("chain_event_change")
            .cum_sum()
            .over("user_id")
        )
        .with_columns(
            event_chain=pl.col("chain_event")
            .cum_sum()
            .over("user_id", "chain_event_identifier")
        )
    )


I don't understand why last 2 rows have event_chain = 0.  shouldn't they have event_chain = 1 because previous rows for user_id = 2 had an event?

event_change should be set to 0 if the user has no events in the next 4 rows, and the current row is not an event. I appreciate that the rule set around this is slightly complex

ok is it next 4 rows or previous 4 rows as written in the original question? Maybe you can add a comment to each row explaining why certain number is assigned

It is both, i will add that now

updated version
I looked at @jqurious answer and I think you can make it even more concise

.sum_horizontal() to precalculate counter while checking previous N rows. We only need sum for previous rows, for next rows we just need to know if they exist, so max is enough.
Also note that we use window of size 5 (including current row) instead so we don't need special case for 'starting' event.

(
    data
    .with_columns(
        chain_event =
           pl.sum_horizontal(pl.col.event.shift(i) for i in range(5))
             .over('user_id'),
        next =
           pl.max_horizontal(pl.col.event.shift(-i) for i in range(1,5))
             .over('user_id').fill_null(False)
    ).with_columns(
        pl
        .when(event = False, next = False).then(0)
        .when(event = False, chain_event = 0).then(0)
        .otherwise(pl.col.chain_event - 1)
        .alias('chain_event')
        # or even shorter but a bit more cryptic
        # pl
        # .when(event = False, next = False).then(0)
        # .otherwise(pl.col.chain_event - pl.col.event)
        # .alias('chain_event')
    )
)

┌─────────┬───────┬──────┬───────┬─────────────┐
│ user_id ┆ event ┆ prev ┆ next  ┆ chain_event │
│ ---     ┆ ---   ┆ ---  ┆ ---   ┆ ---         │
│ i64     ┆ bool  ┆ u32  ┆ bool  ┆ i64         │
╞═════════╪═══════╪══════╪═══════╪═════════════╡
│ 1       ┆ false ┆ 0    ┆ true  ┆ 0           │
│ 1       ┆ true  ┆ 1    ┆ true  ┆ 0           │
│ 1       ┆ true  ┆ 2    ┆ true  ┆ 1           │
│ 1       ┆ false ┆ 2    ┆ true  ┆ 1           │
│ 1       ┆ true  ┆ 3    ┆ false ┆ 2           │
│ 2       ┆ true  ┆ 1    ┆ true  ┆ 0           │
│ 2       ┆ true  ┆ 2    ┆ false ┆ 1           │
│ 2       ┆ false ┆ 2    ┆ false ┆ 0           │
│ 2       ┆ false ┆ 2    ┆ false ┆ 0           │
└─────────┴───────┴──────┴───────┴─────────────┘

previous version

.shift() to get 4 previous and 4 next rows.
.max_horizontal() so we know if there's an event within these windows.
.rle_id() to create continuous groups of events so we can restart the counter.
.cum_sum() to increment counters.
.when().then().otherwise() to only take into account groups with events.

Basically, the most important part here is that we treat row as being within chain if either one of the conditions is met:

There's event within current row.
There's event within previous 4 rows (otherwise we've restarted the counter already) AND there's event within next 4 rows (otherwise we're going to reset the counter).

(
    data
    .with_columns(
        pl.max_horizontal(pl.col("event").shift(i + 1).over('user_id') for i in range(4)).alias("max_lag").fill_null(False),
        pl.max_horizontal(pl.col("event").shift(-i - 1).over('user_id') for i in range(4)).alias("max_lead").fill_null(False)
    ).with_columns(
        event_chain = (pl.col("max_lag") & pl.col("max_lead")) | pl.col('event')
    ).select(
        pl.col('user_id','event'),
        pl.when(pl.col('event_chain'))
        .then(
            pl.col('event').cum_sum().over('user_id', pl.col('event_chain').rle_id().over('user_id')) - 1
        ).otherwise(0)
        .alias('event_chain')
    )
)

┌─────────┬───────┬─────────────┐
│ user_id ┆ event ┆ event_chain │
│ ---     ┆ ---   ┆ ---         │
│ i64     ┆ bool  ┆ i64         │
╞═════════╪═══════╪═════════════╡
│ 1       ┆ false ┆ 0           │
│ 1       ┆ true  ┆ 0           │
│ 1       ┆ true  ┆ 1           │
│ 1       ┆ false ┆ 1           │
│ 1       ┆ true  ┆ 2           │
│ 2       ┆ true  ┆ 0           │
│ 2       ┆ true  ┆ 1           │
│ 2       ┆ false ┆ 0           │
│ 2       ┆ false ┆ 0           │
└─────────┴───────┴─────────────┘

Alternatively

.rolling_max() to calculate if there's event within previous 4 rows
same with .reverse() to calculate if there's event within next 4 rows

(
    data
    .with_columns(
        (pl.col('event').cast(pl.Int32).shift(1).rolling_max(4, min_periods=0)).over('user_id').fill_null(0).alias('max_lag'),
        (pl.col('event').reverse().cast(pl.Int32).shift(1).rolling_max(4, min_periods=0).reverse()).over('user_id').fill_null(0).alias('max_lead')
    ).with_columns(
        event_chain = ((pl.col("max_lag") == 1) & (pl.col("max_lead") == 1)) | pl.col('event')
    ).select(
        pl.col('user_id','event'),
        pl.when(pl.col('event_chain'))
        .then(
            pl.col('event').cum_sum().over('user_id', pl.col('event_chain').rle_id().over('user_id')) - 1
        ).otherwise(0)
        .alias('event_chain')
    )
)


You can count the events using .sum_horizontal() + .shift()
df = (
   df.with_columns(
      previous = 
         pl.when(event = True) 
           .then(pl.sum_horizontal(pl.col.event.shift(N) for N in range(1, 5))
           .over("user_id")),
      next = 
         pl.when(event = False)
           .then(pl.sum_horizontal(pl.col.event.shift(-N) for N in range(1, 5))
           .over("user_id"))
   )
)

shape: (9, 4)
┌─────────┬───────┬──────────┬──────┐
│ user_id ┆ event ┆ previous ┆ next │
│ ---     ┆ ---   ┆ ---      ┆ ---  │
│ i64     ┆ bool  ┆ u32      ┆ u32  │
╞═════════╪═══════╪══════════╪══════╡
│ 1       ┆ false ┆ null     ┆ 3    │
│ 1       ┆ true  ┆ 0        ┆ null │
│ 1       ┆ true  ┆ 1        ┆ null │
│ 1       ┆ false ┆ null     ┆ 1    │
│ 1       ┆ true  ┆ 2        ┆ null │
│ 2       ┆ true  ┆ 0        ┆ null │
│ 2       ┆ true  ┆ 1        ┆ null │
│ 2       ┆ false ┆ null     ┆ 0    │
│ 2       ┆ false ┆ null     ┆ 0    │
└─────────┴───────┴──────────┴──────┘

It then looks like you want to forward fill when event = False unless next = 0
df.with_columns(
   pl.when(event = False, next = 0)
     .then(0)
     .when(event = False)
     .then(pl.col.previous.forward_fill().over("user_id"))
     .otherwise("previous")
     .fill_null(0)
     .alias("event_chain")
)

shape: (9, 5)
┌─────────┬───────┬──────────┬──────┬─────────────┐
│ user_id ┆ event ┆ previous ┆ next ┆ event_chain │
│ ---     ┆ ---   ┆ ---      ┆ ---  ┆ ---         │
│ i64     ┆ bool  ┆ u32      ┆ u32  ┆ u32         │
╞═════════╪═══════╪══════════╪══════╪═════════════╡
│ 1       ┆ false ┆ null     ┆ 3    ┆ 0           │
│ 1       ┆ true  ┆ 0        ┆ null ┆ 0           │
│ 1       ┆ true  ┆ 1        ┆ null ┆ 1           │
│ 1       ┆ false ┆ null     ┆ 1    ┆ 1           │
│ 1       ┆ true  ┆ 2        ┆ null ┆ 2           │
│ 2       ┆ true  ┆ 0        ┆ null ┆ 0           │
│ 2       ┆ true  ┆ 1        ┆ null ┆ 1           │
│ 2       ┆ false ┆ null     ┆ 0    ┆ 0           │
│ 2       ┆ false ┆ null     ┆ 0    ┆ 0           │
└─────────┴───────┴──────────┴──────┴─────────────┘

As it is somewhat complex, it may be desirable to construct the expressions using intermediate variables/functions.
e.g. something like
window_size = 4
window = pl.Series(range(1, window_size + 1))

event_count = lambda window: pl.sum_horizontal(map(pl.col.event.shift, window))
event_count_previous = lambda: event_count(window)
event_count_next = lambda: event_count(-window)

waiting_for_first_event = pl.col.event.cast(int).cum_max() == 0

df.with_columns(event_chain = 
   pl.when(event=True)
     .then(event_count_previous())
     .when(waiting_for_first_event)
     .then(0)
     .otherwise(event_count_next())
     .over("user_id")
)


(uses a slightly different approach to condense it down to a single when/then chain)


nice and clean, I like the way you pre-calculated the counter while checking if it's actually going to be used with shifted sum. You could probably also use .rolling_sum() for that but then you'd need .reverse() to calculate next rows.

Should the waiting_for_first_event not be over("user_id")? This throws an error window expression not allowed in aggregation, but without this, waiting_for_first_event will go to true for every user, when the first event is encountered for any user right?

@cdkdrf The over at the end of pl.when().then().otherwise().over() will be applied to each then/otherwise expression. it is essentially shorthand syntax for repeating .over() inside each branch. I cannot replicate any error - it runs fine for me.
